# Binding a name to my website in IIS 7 on win 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I created a site in iis 7 and bing a name to it.(ggp.sa)

and set its port to 80 and stop default web site and start my own.
by i have a problem.when i want to see it in my browser , i can find it with http://localhost but not with ggp.sa?

where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to your host file:

```
127.0.0.1 ggp.sa
```

The DNS lookup will use the host file value, so it will then make a request to 127.0.0.1, IIS will accept that request and use the host header value to route the request to the appropriate web application.

Comment: oo ya!!!great, but i have a question.why 127.0.0.1?does this IP depend on my local PC IP?thanks for help

Comment: oh sorry, but i cant browse is it in my browser.maybe some setting must be set in my firewall?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, its the typical loopback address that IP/4 loopback networks use, and represents your machine.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of your website configuration?

Comment: which part exactly you meant?

Comment: sorry,i`m new user and can not send picture.instead i put it in my personal website (http://www.ali-foroughi.net/1.jpg) .thanks again